# How to get correct timestamp value in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, swift3, cron

In my project my scheduling to post in social network sites using cron job, 
 timestamp value should end with zero instead of 1.

here is the node js code used:

```
var rule = new cron.RecurrenceRule();
rule.second = 0;
cron.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
var now = new Date();
var date = dateFormat(now, "dd-mm-yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
console.log(Math.floor(new Date()/ 1000));

retrivepost(Math.floor(new Date()/ 1000).toString());
});
```

here is the timestamp value output log which i get in terminal

1517894101
1517894161
1517894221
1517894281
1517894341
1517894401
1517894461
1517894521
1517894581
1517894641
1517894701
1517894761
1517894821
1517894881
1517894941
1517895001
1517895061
1517895121

Answer (score 1):

For me your code works just fine and logs timestamps ending with the zero second just like scheduled.

However, I think if your `retrievepost()` function depends on a timestamp being on the minute exactly you should round your date inside the `.scheduleJob` function to the nearest minute. A whole second later seems odd to me but imagine that you have some code just above that takes a while to compute. `retrievepost()` will fail then, even if you get it working right now.